# How can one tell which ceiling fans are reliable?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I want no wobbling or squeaking for a good long time after I buy it.

I looked in Consumer Reports (annual edition) and they had no ceiling fan ratings.

Google turns up mostly manufacturers explaining their great reliability, and a couple discussion threads [[1]](http://www.homebuyerstalk.com/showthread.php?t=11552)[[2]](http://www.renotalk.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=16787).

Comment: I have very limited experience with this, but have found that with ceiling fans, you do tend to get what you pay for. The Hampton Bay I bought for $100 at Home Depot pales in comparison to the $300 one I bought in a lighting supply store.

Comment: I am surprised this was closed. Internet users don't want to buy ceiling fans?

Comment: "too localized" is odd. Ceiling fan manufacturers are easily national if not international.

Answer (score 1):

For the wobble, for various reasons almost all fans will "wobble" with time.  As with anything that spins they need to be balanced.  Fans require maintenance, and the manual should tell you when and how to do this maintenance.  This involves making sure all screws/bolts are tight, and in the case of wobble it will tell you how to balance the fan.  Fans come with shims and instructions on how to balance the blades.

Comment: This answer is informative, thanks.  However, I still don't know how to judge which ceiling fan is more likely to be reliable.

Comment: @dfrankow I think price is a good indicator for this particular type of product.